# Anaconda python : gcc.exe: error: /Zl: No such file or directory

Tags: python, mysql, ipython, mysql-python, anaconda

please help !! 
I'm trying to resolve some python exercices , so in the begining I was trying to resolve the problem of importing MySQLdb , I used this command : `pip install MySQL-python` under the path `C:\Anaconda\scripts\`
but it gives me this error

```
gcc.exe: error: /Zl: No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1
```

I spent one hour trying to look for a solution but I didn't found anything useful , please help I'm new in using Anaconda and python it is a challenge that I'm taking and I need to send my scripts tomorrow morning !! 
Thank you

Comment: but I though if it is giving me error gcc it means it is already installed no ?

Comment: `No such file or directory` usually means not installed.

Comment: I'm using Anaconda,and OS windows,should I always stay in this path C:\Anaconda\ to apply cmd like pip install MySQL-python ?

Comment: Sounds like `/Zl` from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1tbxcxh.aspx. Seems you have a MSVC polluted environment. Try to run `pip` in a command shell without any environment variables set from `MSVC`.

Comment: Try running `conda remove libpython`

Comment: Hi guys , I wanted to share with you the solution , unfortunately as I said I am a beginner using Anaconda so it's not like using Python only,it was my bad .Anaconda ,you install it in your C drive and in the folder you will find different folders , in which there is Scripts , so I put my .py there when I execute them , I don't face any problem if my code is correct , for the env variable anaconda already make the path in your c so no worries ,

Comment: I 'm still testing Anaconda it is so good for data science engineers if you want to try it :) I'm also learning how to make a flask app that would contain all my scripts etc anyway , I might share some tutorials next time ! bye

Comment: and it contains it's own MinGW folder :-)